# What is the best way to make a listobject binded with datatable

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, listobject

In advance, I'm sorry for my English.
My question is about `ListObject` and `DataTable` with C# for Excel. I used to work a lot with Excel VBA in the past and I understand the concept of `ListObject`. I used to work with C# especially in a ASP.NET context and I can easily figure out about the utility of a `DataTable` object.
Like I thought, `DataTable` and `Listobject` can work together by doing what they are made for :
`ListObject` will be used as a way to display information (but also has some features that allow some fancy operations on data).
`DataTable` his a data container offering complete operations acting mostly like an object where observers (like `DataGridView`) can observe to update their data.
With these lines :

```
fooListObject.AutoSetDataBoundColumnHeaders = true;
fooListObject.SetDataBinding(fooDataTable);
```

It's possible to work on `ListObject` with `DataTable` header names by (adding row, updating cells, etc) and take advantage of the event callbacks of the `DataTable` (executing SQL on changes), but the inverse seems to be possible too.

In my application, I have a `DataTable` linked to a .dbml (LINQ to SQL) object. I also registered a `DataRowChangeEventArgs` event for that `DataTable`.

I want to know the best methods to call on `ListObject` or `DataTable` to update the model with the latest SQL data. I also want to know what should do each one. Right now, if I delete a row in database that I'm not supposed to see in my Excel view, I see it anyways.

Can you tell me more about interaction between `ListObject` and `DataTable`? Some useful methods?

Comment: I have been able to figure out something but I had to forget about LINQ to SQL. Instead of using a `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` object to populate my `DataTable`, I use pure SQL query that I store in a `SqlDataReader` like this `myDataTable.Load(mySQLDataReader)`. Thus, I can use `fooListObject.SetDataBinding(myDataTable);` to work with new data and plenty use `DataRowChangeEventArgs` events.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like the `ListObject.SetDataBinding` Method.

Check this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5f64c2x.aspx

Comment: Hi, I already use the `SetDataBinding `method. What I really looking forward is a way to update the database model to be able to see my data updated in my `ListObject`

Comment: Have you tried the `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` Method?  Check it out here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: From what I read, it can work but it's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut ; sometimes it does not crack only the nut ! Actually, this example shows the inverse of what I'm looking for. I'm not looking to write to server, I want fresh data from the server.